# How can I get the last column when using group by

Tags: sql-server

There is a table _LogEventChar that contains data as shown below:

```
CharID          EventTime           EventID
--------------------------------------------------
1       2019-11-20 05:07:21.130         9   
1       2019-11-20 05:07:19.130         4   
1       2019-11-20 04:45:17.670         6   
1       2019-11-20 04:44:12.670         9   
1       2019-11-20 04:44:08.807         11  
1       2019-11-20 04:44:00.593         9   
1       2019-11-20 04:43:58.470         4       
1       2019-11-20 02:52:49.590         6   
1       2019-11-20 02:37:24.800         9   
1       2019-11-20 02:37:16.667         4   
8       2019-11-20 02:27:50.740         6
8       2019-11-20 02:26:33.567         4
```

If I run a query

```
SELECT CharID, MAX(EventTime) 'EventTime'
FROM dbo._LogEventChar with (NOLOCK)
WHERE EventID in (4, 6)
GROUP BY CharID
```

I will get the result as:

```
CharID      EventTime 
------------------------------------
1       2019-11-20 05:07:19.130
8       2019-11-20 02:27:50.740
```

How can I get the following result:

```
CharID          EventTime           EventID
--------------------------------------------------
1       2019-11-20 05:07:19.130         4
8       2019-11-20 02:27:50.740         6
```

Comment: Why use `NOLOCK` here?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using `WITH TIES` in concert with `row_number()`

**Example**

```
Select top 1 with ties * 
  From  YourTable
  WHERE EventID in (4, 6)
  Order by row_number() over (partition by CharID order by EventTime desc)
```

**Returns**

```
CharID  EventTime                EventID
1       2019-11-20 05:07:19.130  4
8       2019-11-20 02:27:50.740  6
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to filter instead of aggregating. On most RDBMS, the approach that uses a correlated subquery performs very well:

```
select t.*
from dbo._LogEventChar t
where 
    EventID in (4, 6)
    t.EventTime = (
        select max(t1.EventTime)
        from dbo._LogEventChar t1
        where EventID in (4, 6) and t1.CharID = t.CharID
    )
```

For performance with this query, consider an index on `(EventID, CharID, EventTime)`.

Another typical solution is to use `rank()`:

```
select CharID, EventTime, EventID
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        rank() over(partition by CharID order by EventTime desc) rn
    from dbo._LogEventChar t
    where EventID in (4, 6)
) t
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT CharID,
           EventTime,
           EventID,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CharID ORDER BY EventTime DESC) AS RN
    FROM dbo._LogEventChar 
    WHERE EventID in (4, 6))
SELECT CharID,
       EventTime,
       EventID
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```